# Подсветка столбцов между символами табуляции Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Привет, наткнулся на этот скрин, и увидел, что на нём подсвечиваются столбцы между символами табуляции. Я долго искал, как сделать такое или какой пакет мне поможет такого добиться, но ничего найти не смог. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать также?

[image: подсветка табуляции]

Comment: На [**CursorRuler**](https://github.com/icylace/CursorRuler) также можете обратить внимание. Пакет подсвечивает только столбец, где располагается каретка, [**пример**](http://i.imgur.com/xB5SObw.png). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в настройках строки

```
"draw_indent_guides": true,
"indent_guide_options": ["draw_normal"]
```

также можно подсветить вертикальную линию текущего блока

```
"indent_guide_options": ["draw_normal", "draw_active"]
```

[image: Подсветка активной линии]

**Замечание по поводу подсветки вертикальной линии Саша Черных:**  подсвечиваются все вертикальные столбцы сверху и снизу знаков табуляции, находящихся перед первым символом строки, на которой располагается каретка, и столбец, на котором располагается каретка. При этом если столбец сверху или снизу ограничен другим кодом, то, соответственно, выше или ниже он уже не подсвечивается.

[image: Подсветка активной линии]

Comment: **1)** Чтобы настройки вступили в силу, необходимое условие — `"draw_indent_guides": true,`. Полагаю, надо дополнить. **2)** Не могли бы привести скриншот, подтверждающий, что `"indent_guide_options": ["draw_normal", "draw_active"]` выполняет функцию «подсветить текущую линию»? Спасибо.

Comment: а, вот draw_indent_guides не заметил. Поправил.

Comment: Komdosh: попробуйте, если `"indent_guide_options": ["draw_normal", "draw_active"]`, поставить каретку на следующий столбец, затем ещё на следующий: в общем, в разные места Вашего кода. Что у Вас будет подсвечиваться? Спасибо.

Comment: Ну так подсвечивается линия текущего блока. Да в ответе наверное не совсем корректно выразился.

Comment: Komdosh: по слову «линия» не очень понятно, строка это или столбец. Но в любом случае у меня подсвечивается другое — [**скриншот**](http://i.imgur.com/kGoJt3T.png), воспроизвелось на Sublime Text без пользовательских настроек. Попробую выразить: подсвечиваются все вертикальные столбцы сверху и снизу знаков табуляции, находящихся перед первым символом строки, на которой располагается каретка, и столбец, на котором располагается каретка. При этом если столбец сверху или снизу ограничен другим кодом, то, соответственно, выше или ниже он уже не подсвечивается. Спасибо.

Comment: А возможно ли поменять цвет подсветки?

Comment: @Руслан: это определяется в настройках цветовой схемы ключом `guide`. Если, например, [**так**](https://www.pastery.net/pxyndp/), то линии будут красными, [**демонстрация**](http://i.imgur.com/VJRcebs.png). Если не знаете, куда вставлять код, см., например, где он находится [**в моей цветовой схеме**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaSublime/blob/master/SashaSublime.tmTheme#L87-L89). Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных, спасибо)) я так сделал: <key>activeGuide</key>,
 <string>#ff0000</string>, немного поменял тему по умолчанию))))

Comment: Komdosh, по-прежнему полагаю, что определение «линия текущего блока» некорректно в данном случае и поставлю минус, если не будут внесены исправления. Аргументы приведены в комментарии выше. Спасибо.

Comment: @Руслан: `немного поменял тему по умолчанию` — тут такая проблема: если Вы поменяли дефолтный файл цветовой схемы (`тема` в контексте Sublime Text это другое), после обновления Sublime Text настройки снова сбросятся до дефолтных. Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных, а зачем минус? ведь ответ "Komdosh" идеально подходит, я добился того, чего хотел)

Comment: @Руслан, выше в комментариях я пояснил — потому что считаю, что была употреблена некорректная фраза. Сейчас ответ исправлен — поставил плюс. Спасибо.